# XAML property binding confusion

Tags: c#, xaml

Below is the code to an object that I've been playing with to learn XAML and c# ....

It works mostly fine, when the constructor is called it draws a hex polygon on the screen where I want it to go.

I'm trying to set the polygons fill property from it's contructor however and I just can't get this to work.  It dosn't throw any errors, my polygons just remain stubbernly blank.

the code is below, can anyone tell me what my stupid newbie error is please?  Some of the code below is there just for an excuse to use/learn it .... not because it's the bext way to go.

```
<UserControl Name="Hex"
             x:Class="HexControl.HexControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Horizontal Alignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Polygon Name="theHex" Stroke="Black" MouseDown="Polygon_MouseDown" Focusable="True" Fill="{Binding Path=sHexColour}">
            <Polygon.Points>
                <Point>40,30</Point>
                <Point>20,40</Point>
                <Point>0,30</Point>
                <Point>0,10</Point>
                <Point>20,0</Point>
                <Point>40,10</Point>
            </Polygon.Points>

        </Polygon>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

namespace HexControl
{

    public enum Terrain { Clear, Hills, Mountain, Forest, Swamp, Sea };

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class HexControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private string hexID;
        private Terrain hexTerrain;
        private string sHexColour;
        private string[] sColours = {"#FF90EE90", "#FFF4A460", "#FF808080", "#FF006400", "#FF808000", "#FF3CB371"};

        public string sHexID 
        {
            get { return hexID;}
            set { hexID = sHexID; } 
        }

        public Terrain terrain
        {
            get { return hexTerrain; }
            set 
            { 
                hexTerrain = terrain;
                sHexColour = sColours[(int)terrain];
            }
        }


        public HexControl1(string sStartHexID, Terrain startTerrain)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            hexID = sStartHexID;
            hexTerrain = startTerrain;
            sHexColour = sColours[(int)startTerrain];
            //BindingExpression be = theHex.GetBindingExpression(Polygon.FillProperty);
            //be.UpdateSource();
        }

        private void Polygon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Hex Was " + hexID);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't bind a brush to a string. You bind a brush to... a brush. I would give a very high probability to that causing your problem. Are you sure there are *no* `System.Data` errors in your output window.

Comment: Aaahh so my problem is that I have misunderstood that the fill property requires an object of type brush .... rather than simply the colour I want to fill the hext with?

Comment: RIght. When you pass a string on XAML, it will parse it into a brush. To my knowledge, it will never do that when assigned from code.

Comment: Check your output window in Visual Studio for binding errors.

Answer (score 1):

This binding won't work because you are binding `Fill` which is of type `Brush` to a `string` property.

When you write:

```
<Polygon Fill="White"/>
```

The parser goes through and creates a `SolidColorBrush` with the "White" color in it. However, this doesn't work when setting through a binding. If you bind to a `Brush` property instead, your color should appear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but you won't be able to do anything that has to do with bindings while in the constructor. Binding data is only available once the control was loaded, so alternatively, you could subscribe to the control's `Loaded` event or override `OnLoaded` method and put your logic there.

Comment: True, but the constructor can set the initial value which the binding *will* pick up after the constructor is finished. If the binding is set up correctly, it will *appear* to work.

Comment: Correct, but as I see it, `GetBindingExpression` will probably return null and that's the root cause of why other things fail. Again, I'm not really sure what OP is trying to do here, and either way it doesn't seem like he chose the right way to do it.

Comment: Agreed. I would have exposed this as a dependency property so it could be in an `ItemsControl`. I still suspect the root problem is that he is binding a brush to a string.